# Azure-Pipeline is failing test case by prompting identity microsoft window in test result

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Recently I have configured self-hosted agent for pipeline to run the selenium test suite. However it is triggering the test suite now but failing with verify your identity Microsoft window. SSO is also enabled.[image]

Comment: It appears you have enabled MFA on the account. Are you able to run the selenium test with same command on local machine? If it works locally, do you use same user on the pipeline? You can add a bash task with `whoami` to get the username. In addition, it's recommended to share your pipeline log for the test task in the statement which could be helpful for troubleshooting.